# repel function using the ggrepel package

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel, factoextra

How to get around with this error when repel = TRUE function is added to a PCA?

```
fviz_pca_var(
  PCA_Variables,
  col.var = "cos2",
  gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
  geom = c("point", "text"), labelsize = 3, repel = TRUE,
  alpha.var = 0.1
)
```

> Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  :
> Viewport has zero dimension(s)

I tried changing the plot dimensions but giving the same error with when the repel function is included.

Comment: Could you please share your code and some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.